# ¿Cómo hacer update múltiple desde PHP tras una SELECT sin formulario?

Tags: php, mysql, update

Tengo una tabla DATOS con las columnas NUMERO,NOMBRE,REFERENCIA. Las únicas columnas que tienen valor son NUMERO y NOMBRE, REFERENCIA, DATO la extraigo desde una URL. Si ejecuto la select para que a través de la url me devuelva el valor de DATO, funciona ok:

````
require_once('connect.php');
$ReadSql = "SELECT * FROM `DATOS`";
$res = mysqli_query($con, $ReadSql);
include("header.php");
?>
<div style="width: 100%; height: 10px; clear: both;"></div>
<h2>Resultados</h2>
<table class="table"> 
<thead> 
<tr> 
<th>NUMERO</th> 
<th>NOMBRE</th> 
<th>REFERENCIA</th> 
<th>DATO</th>
</tr> 
</thead> 
<tbody> 
<?php 
while($r = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res))
{
$url = "http://URL.asmx/parametro=" . $r['REFERENCIA'];
$xml = simplexml_load_file($url);
$dir = $xml->bico->bi->ldt;
echo "
<tr> 
<td>" . $r['NUMERO']."</td> 
<td>" . $r['NOMBRE']."</td> 
<td>" . $r['REFERENCIA']."</td> 
                <td>" . $dir . "</td>
                        
            </tr> ";
         } ?>
        </tbody> 
        </table>
<?php include ("footer.php"); ?>```

Lo que necesitaria es poder actualizar la tabla para que el valor que me devuelve la URL para cada registro $dir, actualizara la columna DATO de la tabla. Es decir, lo que hace la select funciona, y me muestra la tabla con el valor, pero el valor sólo es un echo, no se almacena. Necesitaría poder almacenar ese valor.
````

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 
while($r = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res))
{
$url = "http://URL.asmx/parametro=" . $r['REFERENCIA'];
$xml = simplexml_load_file($url);
$dir = $xml->bico->bi->ldt;
echo "
<tr> 
<td>" . $r['NUMERO']."</td> 
<td>" . $r['NOMBRE']."</td> 
<td>" . $r['REFERENCIA']."</td> 
                <td>" . $dir . "</td>
                        
            </tr> ";
//Aca fuera del echo constuye tu UPDATE 
$queryUpdate = "UPDATE datos            
                SET NOMBRE={$tuValorDeNombre}, 
                REFERENCIA={$tuValorDeReferencia},
                DATO={$tuValorDeReferencia}
                WHERE (condicion)";
//En tu caso reemplazarias los nombre por ejemplo
// $tuValorDeNombre accederias a el xml como si fuese un objeto
// $xml->nombre; 

         } ?>
```

Comment: Hola @Carlos López, lo primero mil gracias por responder. He puest el código que me indicas, y en el UPDATE lo único que indico es que lo haga sobre DATO que es igual a $dir DATO={$dir}

Comment: Cuando lo ejecuto, no da error pero en la tabla no hay ningún registro actualizado. Todos por defecto tienen la columna vacía pero no la actualiza. Aparte, ¿por qué cuando ejecuta la primera select lo hace sobre mas o menos la mitad de registros y no de todos? Es decir, ejecuta el whlie pero no muestra para todos el valor de $dir, es como si se parase la ejecución. Si lee todos los registros pero digamos que solamente devuelve ese valor para aproximadamente la mitad. gracias de nuevo.

Comment: `$queryUpdate = "UPDATE datos SET DATO={$dir} WHERE NOMBRE='PEPE'";`me actualiza todos al mismo valor